# every time i come to run this command ./gradlew run -Pargs="<message>" he gives me that error

Tags: android, gradle

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task './gradlew' not found in root project 'Android-chat'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3 mins 11.607 secs
 Task './gradlew' not found in root project 'Android-chat'.
 1:15:34 AM: External tasks execution finished './gradlew run --project-prop args="<message>"'.
```

and i don't know what should be done now to fix this.

Comment: Could you post exactly what you entered into the command line?

Comment: Looks like you try to run 'gradle ./gradlew run'. Try './gradlew run' alone.

Comment: ./gradlew run -Pargs="<message>" that what i tried to enter